# Simple Animation using C# for WP

Tags: c#, animation, storyboard, windows-phone

I am trying to create a simple animation using code. I copy pasted the same code of the msdn which is the following:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();
    myRectangle.Width = 200;
    myRectangle.Height = 200;
    Color myColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
    SolidColorBrush myBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    myBrush.Color = myColor;
    myRectangle.Fill = myBrush;

    // Add the rectangle to the tree.
    LayoutRoot.Children.Add(myRectangle);

    // Create a duration of 2 seconds.
    Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
    DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation1 = new DoubleAnimation();
    DoubleAnimation myDoubleAnimation2 = new DoubleAnimation();

    myDoubleAnimation1.Duration = duration;
    myDoubleAnimation2.Duration = duration;

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    sb.Duration = duration;

    sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation1);
    sb.Children.Add(myDoubleAnimation2);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation1, myRectangle);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(myDoubleAnimation2, myRectangle);

    // Set the attached properties of Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top
    // to be the target properties of the two respective DoubleAnimations.
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
             myDoubleAnimation1, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
             myDoubleAnimation2, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));

    myDoubleAnimation1.To = 200;
    myDoubleAnimation2.To = 200;

    // Make the Storyboard a resource.
    LayoutRoot.Resources.Add("unique_id", sb);

    // Begin the animation.
    sb.Begin();
    // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
    //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
}
```

However, I obtain a red square that doesn't move when I run the emulator.
What could be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps because you haven't told it to move? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Move in diagonal downwards

Comment: So what part of the above code tells it to do that?

Comment: Please post the link to the MSDN article you got this code from

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189069(v=vs.95).aspx

Creating an Animation using Procedural Code

Comment: then the only thing I can think of is this: `Note:
Do not attempt to call Storyboard members (for example, the Begin method) in the constructor of the page. This will cause your animation to fail silently.`

Comment: You should use Blend: it will allow you to create your Storyboard visually and produces XAML code which is more maintainable than C# code for UI elements.

Comment: I want to apply the animation to multiple Objects and using different destinations... Is it possible in XAML?